# HTML preprocessor for Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, preprocessor

I'm working on a static HTML prototype without server-side functionality that can easily be distributed on any non-webserver machine to demo.

I'm using LESS for CSS preprocessing to make it easier for me to write CSS.

My HTML files have certain parts that are repeated between all HTML files. This end up in quite a bit of code duplication. Each change results in me updating all those files.

Is there any HTML preprocessor that is supported by Visual Studio (as an extension/addin) that would keep my HTML syntax highlighting and intellisense but add additional features like imports.

What I'd like to have are

- imports parts of HTML that I could simply import into every HTML and just update original template (like head scripts and styles)
- variable definitions that I could also include in HTML that define particular element attributes that would be distributed over files the same way

### What I could use

I was thinking of utilizing T4 which would give me the ability to import templates into HTML files. Resulting HTML files would get transformed on save (or click of a toolbar button) and I could directly use them afterwards.

Downside is I don't get HTML code highlighting and intellisense for HTML code in those T4 templates.

Comment: Bump.  Robert do you mind letting us know what you ended up with?

Comment: @628426 This is so long ago that I can't remember what this was about. Doing it today I'd just use Angular or React for this so that I would be reusing components. Changing a single component would then propagate through all the pages that use them. This would be the easiest thing to do, but if you'd want to complicate things, then the T4 approach is still viable. But a lot more work.